# paypal and credit card fields from braintree api not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I have been trying to follow the guide in the link below to implement a checkout in a rails app I'm working on.
http://www.sitepoint.com/buy-time-braintree-v-zero-sdk/

I am having hard time getting the paypal and credit card fields to show up. I think my problem is here where I tried to add a .js file from vendor/assets/javascripts/braintree.js to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I work at Braintree.</sub>

I downloaded and ran your rails application. I navigated to `/orders/new` and I see a Paypal button as well as credit card fields. Are you still having issues with this?

Regarding `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });`. That line is only necessary if you are running Zurb's Foundation framework. The author of the repository from which you saw that line is using Foundation for styling. Unless you wish to use it as well, you can get rid of that line.